# How to set tor over another proxy?

Tags: proxy, tor

I can't connect tor directly, have to run tor over another proxy. 
I know it is very easy to set by gui on Windows, but how to do this in ubuntu(no gui) ?

For example, I need alter this Dockerfile  https://github.com/mattes/rotating-proxy/blob/master/Dockerfile to accept a environment varriable, which set another proxy for conecting tor network. But I have no idea to set a proxy for tor.

Comment: Are you asking about tor browser? If so it asks while you are setting up, just like on Windows.

Comment: @Artyom no, I want to setup tor as a proxy. But tor can not connect to tor network without a proxy in my country. So it is two layers proxy ,  tor proxy over another http/socks proxy. Is it clear now ？